# Overloaded function differs only by return type

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Confused as to what this error is, visual studio isn't being the most descriptive as what is actually wrong. Can anyone help?

Overloaded function differs only by return type from 'float &vec3::operator[](unsigned int)'

```
/*
 * vec3.cpp
 */
#include <iostream>
#include "vec3.h"

vec3::vec3() {
    data[0] = 0;
    data[1] = 0;
    data[2] = 0;
}
vec3::vec3(float x, float y, float z) {
    data[0] = x;
    data[1] = y;
    data[2] = z;
}
float vec3::operator[](unsigned int index) {             ///Thrown on these 2 functions
    return data[index];
}
const float& vec3::operator[](unsigned int index) const {
    return data[index];
}


/*
 *  vec3.h
 */

#ifndef VEC3_H
#define VEC3_H

class vec3{
private:
    float data[3];
public:
    ///----------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// Constructors
    ///----------------------------------------------------------------------
    vec3();
    vec3(float x, float y, float z);

    ///----------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// Getters/Setters
    ///----------------------------------------------------------------------       
    /// Returns the value at index
    float operator[](unsigned int index) const;

    /// Returns a reference to the value at index
    float& operator[](unsigned int index);
```

Comment: The functions' declaration and definition don't match. Return type: `float` vs `const float&`, `float&` vs `float`.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot overload a method by changing just its return type. The difference must be in the types of arguments in the method description.